# JasperReports: xls format Cell width issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report with A4 size format that generates a excel report. The problem is that at the time of excel generation the cells do not expand horizontally. When the text is bigger than the cell width, and the Excel sheet remains in A4 size even though.

I tried to modify page height and width with following code:

```java
if (this.jasperPrint != null) {
    this.jasperPrint.setPageHeight(10000);
    this.jasperPrint.setPageWidth(100000);
    jasperPrint.setOrientation(jasperReport.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, this.jasperPrint);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, exceloutputStream); //and output stream
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.MAXIMUM_ROWS_PER_SHEET, 65536);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.TRUE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.FALSE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
    xlsexporter.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);

    try {
        xlsexporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        logger.error("generateExcel():Exception in Exporting Excel report" + e);
    }

    this.jasperPrint = null;
}
```

It would be great if anyone can guide me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance